# regex: filter out group starting by a certain string

Tags: html, regex

The text I would like to parse is as follows:

```
<p class="p p1"><strong>Analysts</strong></p>\n<p class="p p1">Mark Troman - BofA Merrill Lynch, Research Division</p>\n<p class="p p1">Ben Uglow - Morgan Stanley, Research Division</p>
```

Using `reg = <p class="p p[1-9][0-9]{0,1}">(.+?)<\/p>`, I can get two groups:

- `<strong>Analysts</strong>`
- `Ben Uglow - Morgan Stanley, Research Division`

However, I want to filter out groups that begin with `<strong>` and end with `</strong>`, and just keep 
`Ben Uglow - Morgan Stanley, Research Division`.

Is there any way to rewrite the regex expression and accomplish the filtering in one-line regex?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to filter out groups that begin with

This regex shall match only groups that don't contain `<strong>` :

`<p class="p p[1-9][0-9]{0,1}">([a-zA-Z0-9, -]+?)<\/p>`